# How does dev tools determine what it can and can't preview in the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I think 'preview' may be the wrong terminology here, feel free to edit.

There is a relatively new feature in the chrome dev tools console giving a live preview of the return of the script you write, when possible.

I've noticed it does not work with particular functions, mainly those that change the state of something. Rightly so, I wouldn't want a state change to be invoked every time a preview is available.

For example, I get a preview here when calling 'dontChangeState()':

[image]

But I do not get a preview here when attempting to increment `myInt`:

[image]

### Question/s

When is script eligible for this preview and when is it not?
What constitutes a 'state change' and how has chrome detected it? Does it scour the contents of my script for anything affecting a variable?

### EDIT

Just to be clear, this is a new Chrome feature whereby executing the function isn't necessary, it provides an insight into what the return will be prior to you executing it. It's a nice feature, and it works as expected (obviously), I'm intrigued as to when it does and doesn't 'work'. I'm not asking about JS syntax or my code specifically.

Comment: I see. So you mean dontChangeState() shows a live preview `"hi"`whereas changeState() doesn’t. Just a guess. Is it because it can just preview immutable functions?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think that is the case, I was looking for some confirmation that it was and other scenarios whereby you can/can't preview.

Comment: `function changeState() { return myInt+1; } changeState()` works. `function changeState(myInt) { myInt++; return "hi"; } changeState(myInt)` this works aswell.

Comment: Well spotted! So anything that changes the state of a variable then? I tried to disguise the state change in a getter, didn't work.

Comment: I think `function changeState() { myInt++; return 'hi'; }` is bad practice, because you take a global var `myInt` and assign it a new value (which could have happened without a function as well). I think this will break the live execution of the return value.

Comment: Just read.....I didn’t mean immutable functions, but pure functions.